# elasticsearch script update based on existing doc value

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

From the [elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference) documentation I came to know that it is easy to search documents using the script on `_search` API, e.g Here I can use the **existing** doc value while making script condition.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['num1'].value > 1",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To update documents using the `Update API` we can do like this,

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.new_field = 'value_of_new_field'"
}
```

What I expect Is that possible on ES query? (**I've tried but not succeeds**)

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.image_count = doc['images'].length;"
}
```

Why I need? Actually I have 2 fields on my document. One called `images` with multiple value e.g **["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.png"]** and another called `image_count` with **3** based on the length of `images` field. Here I can get the length of `images` field while using the `_search` API.

1. But I just want to know is there any facility on ES that I can
   update the every document by dynamically calculating the `images`
   length and set the value of `image_count` field?

**OR**

2. Is there any bulk update API to do that task easily without
   specifying each and every document id on `_update` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is _update_by_query API. Be careful if you have a huge number of docs to update, you can use the sliced scroll approach. 
This works in latest, might have to tweak it depending on your version

```
POST /images_index/_update_by_query
{
    "script":{
        "source": "ctx._source['images_count'] = ctx._source['images'].length"
    }
}
```

See here for doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html